# Python cannot correct length

Tags: python, python-2.7

In a Python script, I have a variable, `key`, output by an AES decryption algorithm that has the value `key = F9hygcyyB2h1S0+2urrsHknqqGPx693s`.

This variable appears to be 32 characters long. However, running `len(key)` returns `48`. Why is this?

```
key
len(key) = 48
type(key) = <type 'str'>, Unicode? False
print (key) = None.
str(key) = F9hygcyyB2h1S0+2urrsHknqqGPx693s
repr(key) = 'F9hygcyyB2h1S0+2urrsHknqqGPx693s\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10'

key = key.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
Length: 48. Type: <type 'str'>, Unicode? False

key = unicode(key)
Length: 48. Type: <type 'unicode'>, Unicode? True

key = key.decode('utf-8')
Length: 48. Type: <type 'unicode'>, Unicode? True
```

#### Answer

The `key` variable is an output of the `AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)` decode process, and I believe the non-printable characters revealed in `repr(key)` are actually padding. Because I know that the key is always supposed to be 32 characters long, this was solved by simply adding:

```
key = key[0:32]
```

This gets rid of all the unprintable characters, and in testing it proves equal to the value expected.

Comment: Your `key` has the length of 32, at least according to my Python 3.4.

Comment: Python 2.7.6 gives 32 as well.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Python len(key) = 48" -- can you be more specific with your question please, it's hard to understand.

Comment: @DYZ I'm using Python 2.7. Regardless, I cannot figure out why that variable is acting strange, but when I call `len(key)`, it returns 48.

Comment: Output of `print type(key)` ?

Comment: What does `print repr(key)` print?

Comment: Could you show us `print (key)`, `str(key)`, and `repr(key)`, just in case?

Comment: @DYZ Added those details.

Comment: Do you any another variable with name key or are using inside dict?

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi I do not - `key` is unique.

Comment: @MYGz `type(key)` is included in the question as 'Type'. It is `<type 'str'>` for the first two and `<type 'unicode'>` for the last two.

Comment: @sscirrus You can get the first 32 chars `key[:32]` The `\x10`s seem to be redundantly appended somewhere in the process. You can ask this question here for more detailed explanation I guess: https://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: Interesting! Don't know whats wrong in your code. I would still put my tryout code in the post.Would delete once you get the answer

Comment: If those `\x10` chars are part of the key it's probably a Good Idea to preserve them! OTOH, if the AES code always uses `\x10` as a padding char it's easy enough to reconstruct the full key when you need it. FWIW, `\x10` is Ctrl-P, which I guess is appropriate for Padding. ;) Traditionally, ^P is the [Data Link Escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#DLE) control character.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the clarification. Is it to retain the length? I found out that default length is 56, 128, 256?

Comment: For those downvoting, suggestions for improvement would be valuable. -1's without that don't help much.

Comment: @MYGz I agree that 48 is a strange length; OTOH, the OP just says it's for "an AES Cipher", so we don't know to what degree it conforms to the standard AES algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have some non-printable characters in the `key`. You can easily get rid of them:

```
newkey = ''.join(x for x in key if x.isprintable()) # Python 3
newkey = ''.join(x for x in key if x in string.printable) # Python 2
len(newkey)
# 32
```

But it's going to be a *different* key!

Comment: I'm getting `'str' object has no attribute 'isprintable'`.

Comment: Updated for Python 2.